# Assign Locust task sets programmatically

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

I am trying to do something where I assign the locust tasks dynamically based on the host value passed through the UI. In this example, if host is passed in as "hello", the test should run the hello task else it should run the world task.

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, events

class RandomTask1(TaskSet):
  @task(1)
  def soemthing(self):
    print("Hello!")

class RandomTask2(TaskSet):
  @task(1)
  def soemthing(self):
    print("World!")

class LoadTestUser(HttpUser):
  def on_start(self):
    host_config = self.host
    if host_config == "hello":
      tasks = {RandomTask1:1}
    else:
      tasks = {RandomTask2:1}
```

The example below does not work and I get the following error

```
Exception: No tasks defined on LoadTestUser. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
```

Any idea how I can achieve something like this? I have simplified this for the example, but for all intents and purposes, let's assume that the locust instance is already running and cannot be stopped or restarted and the tasks need to be assigned dynamically.[image]

Edit:

Tried doing this:

```
class LoadTestUser(HttpUser):
    def on_start(self):
        if self.host == "hello":
            self.tasks = {HelloTask: 1}
        else:
            self.tasks = {WorldTask: 1}

    @task
    def nothing(self):
        pass

class HelloTask(TaskSet):
    @task
    def something(self):
        print("Hello")

class WorldTask(TaskSet):
    @task
    def something(self):
        print("World")
```

Now I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 285, in run
    self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
  File "/Users/user/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 420, in get_next_task
    return random.choice(self.user.tasks)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 291, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single task and put the logic in that task for what you want to have it run.

```
class LoadTestUser(HttpUser):

    def something1(self):
        print("Hello!")

    def something2(self):
        print("World!")

    @task
    def task_logic(self):
        if self.host == "hello":
            self.something1()
        else:
            self.something2()
```

However, you can just address the error you're getting directly. You need to have a task defined in the class even if you intend to overwrite or change the tasks with your TaskSets. There's an example [in the documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/tasksets.html) but just add a task with `pass` so it doesn't do anything, then your overrides should work.

```
class LoadTestUser(HttpUser):

    def on_start(self):
        host_config = self.host
        if host_config == "hello":
            self.tasks = {RandomTask1:1}
        else:
            self.tasks = {RandomTask2:1}

    @task
    def nothing(self):
        pass
```

**EDIT:**
This **should** work but looks like there could be a bug in the current version of Locust where it only accepts a dictionary for tasks when Locust first starts and then only accepts a list afterward. Until it's fixed, the example in the other answer works.

Comment: That will be hard to manage because I have a lot of tasks and a lot of hosts to deal with. Each host type needs to have its own task set essentially and I want to load that task set dynamically.

Comment: Without more information, I don't think I'll understand. This works, even if you have lots of tasks and hosts to deal with. Based on the example you gave, this is essentially the same thing but more straightforward and you don't need to worry about complexity. But there may be another way. I can edit my answer to add another option.

Comment: You are right that this will work with a lot of tasks and hosts, but what do you suggest if I want the task weights to be different for different hosts?

Comment: It's possible to handle your own logic for weighting. How you do it will depend on exactly what you want, but it's often not as difficult as it seems at first. Usually just another if with a random number choice. If you need a 10:1 weighting between 2 tasks, if random between 0 and 10 is 0, do the 1 task, else do the 10 task.

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting in your second code snippet and looks like the override does not happen. I think the task set needs to be assigned on class load and not when the runner is starter.

Also, for the first snippet consider this scenario:
if I have 2 tasks: task1 & task2. For host1 I want the weight of 1:1 and if it host2, I want the task weighting to to 1:5. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Oh, I forgot the `self`. `tasks` is an attribute of the class. Without `self.tasks` in the `on_start()` method, your `tasks` is just a local variable. I'll fix it.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as setting the tasks via an instance variable on start. I'm seeing this weird error from the random library now. Added to the original post.

Comment: Had to tweak it a little bit to work with task weights and all. I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, events

class LoadTestUser(HttpUser):
    def locust_class(self, name):
        module = sys.modules[__name__]
        return getattr(module, f"{name.capitalize()}Task")

    def get_weighted_tasks(self, task_list):
        new_tasks = []
        for item in task_list:
            if "locust_task_weight" in dir(item):
                for i in range(item.locust_task_weight):
                    new_tasks.append(item)
        return new_tasks

    def get_locust_tasks(self, cls):
        tasks = []
        for maybe_task in cls.__dict__.values():
            if hasattr(maybe_task, "locust_task_weight"):
                tasks.append(maybe_task)
        return tasks

    def on_start(self):
        task_cls = self.locust_class(self.host)
        task_list = self.get_locust_tasks(task_cls)
        self.tasks = self.get_weighted_tasks(task_list)

    @task(1)
    def nothing(self):
        pass


class HelloTask(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def something(self):
        print("Hello")

    @task(100)
    def something_else(self):
        print("hello")


class WorldTask(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def something(self):
        print("World")

    @task(10)
    def something_else(self):
        print("world")
```